# AFURLSessionManager when my ViewController was navigated app crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8, afnetworking

I have problem in AFURLSessionManager for Objective-C iOS. I have 2 viewController and use AFURLSessionManager for getData from server.

when user navigate to viewContoller2 that have AFURLSessionManager request and user has very bad network and press back button, AFURLSessionManager want to call delegate, crashed and show **EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

[image: Crash image]

when i navigate to a viewController, AFURLSessionManager task finish late and viewController was changed by user and AFURLSessionManager try call delegates not exists in MEMORY.

Anyone has any idea fix this problem?

This is request code :

```
- (void) getData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"http://----------" parameters:nil error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    req.timeoutInterval= 15;
    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    self.dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {

         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Reply JSON >>>>>> responseObject <<<<<: %@", responseObject);


             if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
             {
                 if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(success:)]) {
                     [self.delegate success:responseObject];
                 }
                 //                  self.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                 return;
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error No dictionary: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
                 {
                     //                      self.colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                     [self.delegate error:error];
                     return;
                 }

             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
             [self.delegate error:error];
             return;

         }

     }];

    [self.dataTask resume];

    if (self.cancelRequest) {
        [self.dataTask cancel];
    }
}
```

header file :

```
@protocol WebServicesDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) success:(NSDictionary *) dic;
- (void) error:(NSError *) error;

@end

@interface WebServices : NSObject

@property (assign,nonatomic) id<WebServicesDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL cancelRequest;

-(void) setCancelRequest:(BOOL)cancelRequest;
//+(instancetype) shareInstance;

- (void) getData;

@end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show some code what had you tried out!

Comment: Update my question and enter my codes

Comment: Please update ypur question with crash logs as well.

Comment: You are calling the delegate so please check the responseObject is getting nil or not if not then call delegate before getting the responseObject you are getting back to view controller that'y getting crashed

Comment: In which line app crash ?                      [self.delegate success:responseObject];
 or                      [self.delegate error:error];

Comment: crashed in if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(success:)])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug what self.delegate is. It is definitely not nil otherwise it wouldn't have crashed.

It crashed because self.delegate is not an NSObject subclass. It is either a scalar or some garbage value.

I guess you have used `assign` instead of `weak` while declaring delegate and because it is assigned, it is resulting in a dangling pointer.

**EDIT**(after question update)
Change

```
@property (assign,nonatomic) id<WebServicesDelegate> delegate;
```

to

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<WebServicesDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: i enter my header file, my delegate is NSObject and assign

Comment: Thats why it is crashing. Change assign to weak.

Answer (score 1):

Issue may be with the `self` as your `webservice` is async so when the response comes you have already removed that viewcontroller by pop or dismiss

you should use     `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`

and use  `weakSelf` at the place of `self`

Hope it helps to solve your issue

Comment: i thinks it can help me, i try to use this. thanks dude

Comment: It wouldnt have crashed thugh, may result in memory leak but not crash.

Comment: @HusseinHabibiJuybari   I have faced this kind of issue many times. We should keep weak ref every time if there is async task is going on and chances to nil self !! and also always keep delegate weak

Comment: @MikeAlter: I know and you are right but they dont result in crashes. The OP is using assign instead of weak and it is resulting in a dangling pointer when the reference saved in that delegate is getting nil.

Comment: @HusseinHabibiJuybari it is also helpful when you . are doing UI Stuff in that block (property of self ) , i.e change label value with some response will not crash any more !!

Comment: @MikeAlter I didn't know "should keep weak ref every time if there is async task". thanks dude.