# How to gracefully logout of an iOS app using Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, logout

This is a pretty common problem when using asynchronous tasks and core data. When you logout from an App, you want your app to go back to it's very first state: No database created for example.

GIVEN

- You have a User NSManagedObject
- You send a request to your server that will take 4 sec to come back. ( This request can be a request made by the app after the user updated his user name a second ago for example)
- You have an observer in User

code:

```
addObserver(self, keyPath: #keyPath(User.firstname) as NSString, options: [], block: { (notification) in
      (notification?.target as? User)?.updateFirstNameFormat()
    })
```

WHEN

- You logout your app and context and user NSManagedObject are destroyed
- the server request triggers a callback
- This callback updates the User object (strong reference) first name.

THEN

- You get an observer crash when trying to update the first name format.

**This crash will be pretty random because the User destruction is decided by the system. With Core Data, only trying to access the User object property firstname can trigger a crash when the managed object doesn't actually exist anymore**

Is there a good way to prevent similar use cases?

Comment: Why don't you logout after server response comes? Unable to understand your concern

Comment: Because when the user decides to logout, he presses the button and the app goes back to its initial state. The server request I m talking about could be any network request. for example, change user name, get data that are linked to the user and have to be processed in the callback for example. Network requests here are not related to the logout.

Comment: You should use weak self for ws calling, When response comes  check weather self is niil or not  however user logout means  self is deallocated (due to go to inital state) , see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768864/4601900

Comment: Yes, weak self is important. In theory this should work, I ll investigate more on this side.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the app releases only some coredata objects before releasing other classes (the ones who start the webservice requests). That would cause a crash.